# Apply Github hosted Kubernetes file with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile, kind

I am trying to set up a helmfile deployment for my local kubernetes cluster which is running using 'kind' (a lightweight alternative to minikube). I have charts set up for my app which are all deploying correctly, however I require an nginx-ingress controller. Luckily 'kind' provides one, which I am currently applying with the command:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/kind/deploy.yaml`

It seems perverse that I should have everything else set up to deploy at the touch of a button, but still have to 'remember' (and also train my colleagues to remember...) to run this additional command.

I realise I could copy and paste and create my own version, but I would like to keep up to date with any changes made at source. Is it possible to create a chart that makes a reference to an external template?

I am looking at solutions using either helm or helmfile.

Answer (score 1):

Your linked YAML file seems to have been generated from the [ingress-nginx](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx) chart.

### Subchart

You can include ingress-nginx as a subchart in Helm 3 by adding it as a dependency to your own chart. In Helm 3, this is done with the `dependencies` field in `Chart.yaml`, e.g.:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: my-chart
version: 0.1.0
dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    version: ~4.0.6
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    condition: ingress-nginx.enabled
```

This may be problematic, however, if you need to install multiple versions of your own chart in the same cluster.  To handle this, you'd need to consider the implications of [multiple Ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/).

### Chart

Ingress controllers are capable of handling ingresses from various releases across multiple namespaces.  Therefore, I would recommend maintaining ingress-nginx separately from your own releases that depend on it.  This would mean installing ingress-nginx like you already are or as a separate chart ([guide](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx#install-chart)).

If you go this route, there are tools that help make it easier for devs to take a hands-off approach for setting up their K8s environments.  Some popular ones include [Skaffold](https://skaffold.dev/), [DevSpace](https://devspace.sh/), [Tilt](https://tilt.dev/), and [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile).